# How to fix "Error using hac (line 485) - Index exceeds array bounds''

Tags: matlab, regression, autocorrelation

When using HAC to get heteroskedacity corrected weights for my regression model, the function crashes on line 485 of hac.m: `b = getBW(V,weights,model,iFlag);`

My used regression model has 17 variables (1 constant + 16 regressors).
This getBW function fails in the loop starting at line 872 of hac.m because ARfit.AR{1} is empty after the second iteration of this loop, and I don't know why.
I simply use:

```
EstCov = hac(X,y)
```

where `X = [224x17]` and `y = [224x1]`

Trying something like:

```
DataTable = array2table([X,y],'VariableNames',{'X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','X10','X11','X12','X13','X14','X15','X16','X17','Y'});
OLSModel = fitlm(DataTable);
[EstCov,se,coeff]=hac(OLSModel,'display','full');
```

also fails at the same point for the same reason. Why won't `hac(X,y)` work? I keep getting

> Error using hac (line 485)
>   Index exceeds array bounds.

Comment: Have you tried transposing `[X,y]`?

Comment: Yes, but that results in:
`Error using hac (line 340)
Predictor and response variables must have the same length.` Transposing only the y array doesn't give that error, but the same old one again: `Error using hac (line 485) Index exceeds array bounds.`

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] to see what happens